# FROM address for system emails on Linux (Postfix)

Tags: postfix, sendmail

I have an unbuntu server using `sendmail` and `postfix` to send `apticron`, `cron` etc emails.

`postfix` is configured to use a smart relay, the smart relay is rejecting emails as they come from the subdomain of the server rather than the domain.

So, I have a server called `backup` on `mydomain.com` emails were set with a `From:` header of `backup.mydomain.com` and our relay is only configured to allow emails from `mydomain.com`. I don't want to change this.

So in `postfix`'s `main.cf` I added `masquerade_domains` for `mydomain.com`, which if I'd read the [docs][1] right would mean that `backup` would be stripped out of the from to result in emails `From: foo@backup.mydomain.com` coming as `From: foo@mydomain.com`

However, I am now getting emails `From: root@backup`

`main.cf`

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = backup.mydomain.com
masquerade_domains = mydomain.com
mydomain = mydomain.com
myorigin = $mydomain
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname, backup.mydomain.com, backup, localhost.localdomain, localhost
```

Suggestions appreciated. I've seen various other posts with complex changes to `sendmail` and other solutions, but, they don't seem right as I'm just trying to get the email to be from `user@domain.com` for a named server in the domain, which I understand to be a `postfix` concern and `masquerade_domains` seems to be the documented solution.
[1]: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#masquerade_domains